# How to store current counter in collect file

Tags: counters, expansion, collect

I want to store the number of Exam in `collect` environment.
 The counter is alway store with final value. PLease help me correct my code with **collect** package.
 Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\definecollection{excol}
\newcounter{excout}
\newenvironment{exam}{
    \refstepcounter{excout}
    \begin{center}
        THE EXAM \theexcout
    \end{center}
    \begin{collect}{excol}{}{}{}{}
        The exam {\Large \theexcout} 
    \end{collect}
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{exam}
Content 1
\end{exam} 
\begin{exam}
Content 1
\end{exam} 

\bigskip
\includecollection{excol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I add another counter. I works well. I think that it can be had a better solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{collect}
\definecollection{excol}
\newcounter{excoutP}
\def\st{}
\newcommand{\inso}{
    \refstepcounter{excoutP}
    \appto\st{\theexcoutP}
    \st
}
\newcounter{excout}
\newenvironment{exam}{
    \refstepcounter{excout}
    \begin{center}
        THE EXAM \textcolor{red}{\theexcout}
    \end{center}
    \begin{collect}{excol}{}{}{}{}
        The exam {\Large \textcolor{red}{\inso}} 
    \end{collect}
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{exam}
Content 1
\end{exam} 
\begin{exam}
Content 1
\end{exam} 

\bigskip
\includecollection{excol}
\end{document}
```